# Elasticsearch script_score with array

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use script_score to update the score based on a json of ID values. The score should multiply the original score by the factor listed in params.

```
"script_score": {
    "params": {
      "ranking": {
        "1": "1.3403946161270142",
        "3": "1.3438195884227753"
       }
    },
    "script": "_score * ranking[doc['ID'].value]"
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
nested: QueryParsingException[[index name] script_score the script could not be loaded]; nested: CompileException[[Error: unbalanced braces [ ... ]]\n[Near : {... _score * ranking[doc['ID'].value] ....}]\n                                         ^\n[Line: 1, Column: 29]]; }]"
```

If I manually specify an ID for example _score * ranking['1'], it works fine. Also if I use the ID directly it works, but not if I use the ID value as the index. I should note that the ID is an integer. Can anyone help me solve this? Additionally, how would this work if the ID isn't in the ranking list? Would it treat it as score='_score'?

Answer (score 1):

You `ranking` param is not an array but a map. The type used for the `ID` field should match the type used for the key in your map, and the boost should be a number, not a string.

Here is a document:

```
{
  "ID" : "1"
}
```

and here is the updated query:

GET /test/_search

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "params": {
              "ranking": {
                "1": 1.3403946161270142,
                "3": 1.3438195884227753
              }
            },
            "script": "_score * ranking.get(_doc['ID'].value)"
          } 
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The current script doesn't handle cases where the entry is not within the parama map, case that leads to a `NullPointerException`.

That said I think this boosting method will not scale as you need to have an entry per document in your params, which is hardly maintainable. Having the rank within each of the document seems better although you'd need to update them every time you want to change it.